# Compare Two Array, if found same key get the value from 2nd Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare

How to compare two arrays, and if found the same key and then get the value from 2nd array and assign it to first array. And the result is using first array. for example I have the array below:

```
    var compareit = {
            firstArray : {
                'color': 'blue',
                'width': 400,
                'height': 150,
            },
            secondArray: {
                'color': 'red',
                'height': 500,
            },
    };
```

The goal is, I want the result will : `{'color': 'red', 'width': '400', 'height': '500'};`

I really appreciate with any help...Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy values from one or more source objects to a target object.

```js
 var compareit = {
   firstArray: {
     'color': 'blue',
     'width': 400,
     'height': 150,
   },
   secondArray: {
     'color': 'red',
     'height': 500,
   },
 };

 Object.assign(compareit.firstArray, compareit.secondArray);
 console.log(compareit.firstArray)
```

If you don't want to manipulate existing object `compareit.firstArray`

```js
var compareit = {
  firstArray: {
    'color': 'blue',
    'width': 400,
    'height': 150,
  },
  secondArray: {
    'color': 'red',
    'height': 500,
  },
};

var obj = {};
Object.assign(obj, compareit.firstArray, compareit.secondArray);
console.log(obj, compareit)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the properties in the first array, and check if the same property exists in the second array.

```js
var compareit = {
  firstArray: {
    'color': 'blue',
    'width': 400,
    'height': 150,
  },
  secondArray: {
    'color': 'red',
    'height': 500,
  },
};
var result = {};
for (var key in compareit.firstArray) {
  if (key in compareit.secondArray) {
    result[key] = compareit.secondArray[key];
  } else {
    result[key] = compareit.firstArray[key];
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var compareit = {
            firstArray : {
                'color': 'blue',
                'width': 400,
                'height': 150,
            },
            secondArray: {
                'color': 'red',
                'height': 500,
            },
    };
var result,
    compareObjects=function(comp){
      return Object.assign(comp.firstArray, comp.secondArray);
    };

result=compareObjects(compareit);
console.log(result);
```